# How to reverse timeline created using streamlit-timeline?

Tags: python, json, timeline, streamlit

I am trying to create a Career timeline in a streamlit web app using the streamlit-timeline python package. Though I am able to create it using TimelineJS format as mentioned in the documentation, The oldest item shows up first & so on. I wish to reverse this timeline to show the latest event first. How can I do this?

The current web app: https://mehulgupta2016154-resume-builder-streamlit-app-ajmqjx.streamlitapp.com/

streamlit-timeline: https://pypi.org/project/streamlit-timeline/

Comment: What have you tried? Reversing the json entry does not work as it operates on start_date. The TimelineJS itself does not support such feature. There is a trick to reverse the display, but the timeline display in the bottom is compressed. But generally it worked.

Comment: Couldn't find anything on the internet for this. Can you hare the trick you mentioned

Comment: Change the start_date year to negative value.